# nth-child beginning from middle of the html

Tags: css

I may have random html......

```
<div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
....
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
...
<p></p>
<p></p>
....
</div>
```

Now, I want to count to heading as first second third etc child. For eg. if I set h1:first-child{} then it will not select as in the above example because it's not in first position of div.

So, how can I style assuming nth-child(1) for first h1 nth-child(2) for second h2 etc?

Comment: Check the bottom of this page: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class. `h1:nth-of-type(5)` will match the fifth `h1` element, regardless of where it is.